# Sobreposição de valores na matriz

Tags: c, matriz

Ola tenho uma matriz que é formada por um conjunto de números aleatórios. Contudo alguns desses conjuntos de números sobrepõem-se. O que posso fazer ara isso nao acontecer?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
void ransnipa(int (*board)[40]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int k;
    int x[snipa];
    int y[snipa];


    for(k=0 ; k < snipa ;k++){
        x[k]= rand() % 39;
        y[k]= rand() % 39;

        do{

            x[k]= rand() % 39;
            y[k]= rand() % 39;

        }while(( (board[x[k]][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]+1]) && (board[x[k]][y[k]+1])) == -1);

        board[x[k]][y[k]]=2;
        board[x[k]+1][y[k]]=2;
        board[x[k]+1][y[k]+1]=2;
        board[x[k]][y[k]+1]=2;



    }

}
void rantank(int (*board)[40]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int k;
    int x[tank];
    int y[tank];
    int ant;

    for(k=0 ; k < tank ;k++){
        x[k]= rand() % 39;
        y[k]= rand() % 39;

        do{

            x[k]= rand() % 39;
            y[k]= rand() % 39;

        }while(((board[x[k]][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]+1]) && (board[x[k]][y[k]+1]) && (board[x[k]][y[k]-1]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]-1]) && (board[x[k]-1][y[k]-1]) && (board[x[k]-1][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]-1][y[k]+1])) == -1);

        board[x[k]][y[k]]=3;
        board[x[k]+1][y[k]]=3;
        board[x[k]+1][y[k]+1]=3;
        board[x[k]][y[k]+1]=3;

        board[x[k]][y[k]-1]=3;
        board[x[k]+1][y[k]-1]=3;
        board[x[k]-1][y[k]-1]=3;
        board[x[k]-1][y[k]]=3;
        board[x[k]-1][y[k]+1]=3;

    }

}
```

Comment: Amigo não tem como postar o código fonte completo (pelo Git ou aqui mesmo)? Pois estou presumindo que as variáveis `tank` e `snipa` sejam declarados globalmente. Caso isso seja verdade, muito provavelmente estas variáveis foram sobrescritas/alteradas. Algumas soluções: - Utilizar `const` para deixar as variáveis globais seguras de uma eventual sobrescrita; - Utilizar `#define NOME_DA_VARIAVEL VALOR`; - Não utilizar variável global; Infelizmente não posso opinar melhor, pois não consigo depurar e rastrear o código.

Comment: O que você está querendo testar com esta condição: (((board[x[k]][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]+1]) && (board[x[k]][y[k]+1]) && (board[x[k]][y[k]-1]) && (board[x[k]+1][y[k]-1]) && (board[x[k]-1][y[k]-1]) && (board[x[k]-1][y[k]]) && (board[x[k]-1][y[k]+1])) == -1)? O que você espera como resultado das operações && (E lógico) sobre inteiros?